# How to make an Expandable ListView without child items

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I am new with ExpandableListView in NavigationDrawer. My problem is, All the header menus which are having submenus are expanding and collapsing properly but those header menus which are not having any submenus are crashing my application with the NullPointerException. Here my code

```
listDataHeader.add("Home");
listDataHeader.add("Bhopal");
listDataHeader.add("Indore");
listDataHeader.add("Jaipur");
listDataHeader.add("Udaipur");
listDataHeader.add("Ajmer");
listDataHeader.add("Jodhpur");
listDataHeader.add("Chandigarh");
listDataHeader.add("Lakhnow");

// Adding child data
List<String> bhopal_ = new ArrayList<String>();
bhopal_.add("About Us");
bhopal_.add("Board Members");
bhopal_.add("Chaiman Messages");

List<String> indore_ = new ArrayList<String>();
indore_.add("Heritage of Indore");
indore_.add("City Map");

List<String> udaipur_ = new ArrayList<String>();
udaipur_.add("Live");
udaipur_.add("Old");

List<String> lakhnow_ = new ArrayList<String>();
lakhnow_.add("Procurement");
lakhnow_.add("Schemes");
lakhnow_.add("Auctions");

listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(1), bhopal_); // Header, Child data
listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(2), indore_);
listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(4), udaipur_);
listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(8), lakhnow_);
```

This is my adapter code

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {

    Context mContext;
    List<String> listDataHeader;
    HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild;

    public ExpandableListAdapter(Context mContext, List<String> listDataHeader, HashMap<String, List<String>> listDataChild) {
        this.mContext = mContext;
        this.listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
        this.listDataChild = listDataChild;
    }

    @Override
    public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
        return this.listDataChild.get(this.listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).get(childPosititon);
    }

    @Override
    public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return childPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
        return listDataChild.get(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();
    }

    @Override
    public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
        return listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
    }

    @Override
    public int getGroupCount() {
        return listDataHeader.size();
    }

    @Override
    public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
        return groupPosition;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasStableIds() {
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public View getGroupView(int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
        String header_title = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext.getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.sub_menu_list_group, null);
        }

        TextView tv_head_txt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
        tv_head_txt.setText(header_title);
        tv_head_txt.setTypeface(Utilities.myFont(mContext));

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public View getChildView(int groupPosition, int childPosition, boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

        final String child_title = String.valueOf(getChild(groupPosition, childPosition));
        if (convertView == null) {
            LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.mContext
                    .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
            convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.menu_list_item, null);
        }

        TextView tv_head_txt = (TextView) convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);
        tv_head_txt.setText(child_title);
        tv_head_txt.setTypeface(Utilities.myFont(mContext));

        return convertView;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
        return true;
    }
}
```

Exception is arrived when there no submenus at specific header menus.

Answer (score 1):

Your **groupPosition** was coming **null** , thats why it was crashing. you can try this below code.

```
@Override
    public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
      int pos =0;
    if(groupPosition != null){
          if( (listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)!= null) && (listDataChild.get(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size() != null)){
           pos  =  listDataChild.get(listDataHeader.get(groupPosition)).size();
        }else{ 
          pos =0;
        } 
    }
    return pos;
    }
```

Comment: when i clicked at Bhopal i.e. at first position  System.out:groupPosition-- > 1 childPosition-- > 0
        System.out:groupPosition-- > 1 childPosition-- > 1
        System.out:groupPosition-- > 1 childPosition-- > 2
        System.out:groupPosition-- > 1 childPosition-- > 3
        System.out:groupPosition-- > 1 childPosition-- > 4

Comment: and is it crashing if you click on Bhopal

Comment: but again when i clicked at Home i.e. 0 position App get crashed

Comment: no when i clicked on Bhopal Menus was expanding properly

Comment: hello Nidhi , did you try to the updated answer it will work for you 100%

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException
                                                                                   at com.example.administrator.ida.Adapter.ExpandableListAdapter.getChildrenCount

Comment: okay just one time more pls try the updated answer i just now updated

Comment: it will avoid your crash , did you try

Comment: inside this     public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
 method can you put log to print groupPosition

Comment: and then can u tell me the value when it crashs

Comment: if you are here , then you can use the above code , error was your group position was coming null ,

Comment: Hello , nidhi as it helped can you accept &upvote this answer here

Answer (score 0):

You just initialize the list as follows,

```
 listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(3), new ArrayList<String>());
 listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(5), new ArrayList<String>());
 listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(6), new ArrayList<String>());
 listDataChild.put(listDataHeader.get(7), new ArrayList<String>());
```

which may solve your problem

Answer (score -1):

set it as 0.

```
 @Override
public int getChildrenCount(int i) {
    return listDataChild.get(listDataHeader.get(i)).size()>0?listDataChild.get(listDataHeader.get(i)).size():0;
}
```

Comment: thanks for your answer but this is not allowing other menus get expand.